# Can you train a BERT model from scratch with task specific architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

BERT pre-training of the base-model is done by a language modeling approach, where we mask certain percent of tokens in a sentence, and we make the model learn those missing mask. Then, I think in order to do downstream tasks, we add a newly initialized layer and we fine-tune the model.

However, suppose we have a gigantic dataset for sentence classification. Theoretically, can we initialize the BERT base architecture from scratch, train both the additional downstream task specific layer + the base model weights form scratch with this sentence classification dataset only, and still achieve a good result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BERT can be viewed as a language encoder, which is trained on a humongous amount of data to learn the language well. As we know, the original BERT model was trained on the entire English Wikipedia and Book corpus, which sums to **3,300M** words. BERT-base has 109M model parameters. So, if you think you have large enough data to train BERT, then the answer to your question is yes.

However, when you said "still achieve a good result", I assume you are comparing against the original BERT model. In that case, the answer lies in the size of the training data.

I am wondering why do you prefer to train BERT from scratch instead of fine-tuning it? Is it because you are afraid of the domain adaptation issue? If not, pre-trained BERT is perhaps a better starting point.

Please note, if you want to train BERT from scratch, you may consider a **smaller** architecture. You may find the following papers useful.

- [Well-Read Students Learn Better: On the Importance of Pre-training Compact Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08962)
- [ALBERT: A Lite BERT for Self-supervised Learning of Language Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11942)

Comment: You are exactly correct. I had to slightly modified the base BERT architecture so I can't use a pretrained base-bert. and my 200k dataset is highly domain specific. My original idea was to train BERT from scratch using these 200k dataset with the language modeling architecture, then fine-tune it again for task specific task, but I was curious if I could just skip the language model training and directly train a task specific task, but still achieve similar result because for both pre-training and fine-tuning, I am using the same dataset. (I think it is repetitive). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wasi Ahmad, please how can I finetune the BERT model on my own dataset in python?

Comment: @nour the [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/official_models/fine_tuning_bert)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MLM and NSP (which are the original pre-training objectives from NAACL 2019) are meant to train language encoders with prior language knowledge. Like a primary school student who read many books in the general domain. Before BERT, many neural networks would be trained from scratch, from a clean slate where the model doesn't know anything. This is like a newborn baby.

So my question is, "is it a good idea to start teaching a newborn baby when you can begin with a primary school student?" My answer is no. This is supported by numerous State-of-The-Arts achieved by the pre-trained models, compared to the old methods of training a neural network from scratch.

As someone who works in the field, I can assure you that it is a much better idea to fine-tune a pre-trained model. It doesn't matter if you have a 200k dataset or a 1mil datapoints. In fact, more fine-tuning data will only make the downstream results better if you use the right hyperparameters.

Though I recommend the learning rate between 2e-6 ~ 5e-5 for sentence classification tasks, you can explore. If your dataset is very, very domain-specific, it's up to you to fine-tune with a higher learning rate, which will deviate the model further away from its "pre-trained" knowledge.

---

And also, regarding your question on

> can we initialize the BERT base architecture from scratch, train both the additional downstream task specific layer + the base model weights form scratch with this sentence classification dataset only, and still achieve a good result?

I'm negative about this idea. Even though you have a dataset with 200k instances, BERT is pre-trained on 3300mil words. BERT is too inefficient to be trained with 200k instances (both size-wise and architecture-wise). If you want to train a neural network from scratch, I'd recommend you look into LSTMs or RNNs.

I'm not saying I recommend LSTMs. Just fine-tune BERT. 200k is not even too big anyways.